# How to get a button to link to another HTML template in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django, I'm trying to get a button on the homepage to link to another (as of right now) static page.

I thought this was pretty simple, I've done frontend work before and a simple href to the file would be enough but for some reason its not linking.

```
<h1> This is the homepage yay!</h1>
<div class="container">
  <a href="./scoringsheet.html" class="btn btn-1">Judges</a>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-2">Students</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question well, you would have to create a view and put its url in the template.

```
def scoring_sheet(request):
    return render(request, 'scoringsheet.html', {})
```

And register in your url:

```
path('yourapp/scoring_sheet', views.scoring_sheet, name='scoring-sheet'),
```

and add in html;

```
<h1> This is the homepage yay!</h1>
<div class="container">
  <a href="{% url 'scoring-sheet' %}" class="btn btn-1">Judges</a>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-2">Students</button>
</div>
```